# Virtuoso Sesame Provider displays the blank page when clcik on new repo

Tags: sesame, virtuoso

I have configured my sesame according to this tutorial (http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtSesame2HttpRepository) to add virtuoso extension into it . When i click on new repository, it display blank page. Can anyone tell me where i did mistake.

I just performed the following steps.

Setup Sesame HTTP Repository

This section details the steps required for configuring and testing a Virtuoso HTTP Sesame Repository.

```
Install Apache Tomcat web server
From the Sesame 2.3.1 or higher "lib" directory copy the "openrdf-sesame.war" and "openrdf-worbbench.war" files to the tomcat "webapps" directory where they will automatically be deployed creating two new sub directories "openrdf-sesame" and "openrdf-workbench".
Place the Virtuoso Sesame Provider "virt_sesame2.jar" and JDBC Driver "virtjdbc3.jar" into the Tomcat ~/webapps/openrdf-sesame/WEB-INF/lib/ and ~/webapps/openrdf-workbench/WEB-INF/lib/ directories for use by the Sesame HTTP Repository for accessing the Virtuoso RDF repository.
Place the "create.xsl" and "create-virtuoso.xsl" files in the Tomcat ~/webapps/openrdf-workbench/transformations/ directory. Note "create.xsl" replaces the default provided with Sesame and contains the necessary entries required to reference the new "create-virtuoso.xsl" template file for Virtuoso repository configuration.
The Sesame HTTP Repository will now be accessible on the URLs


http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame
http://localhost:8080/openrdf-workbench


The Sesame OpenRDF Workbench is used for accessing the Sesame HTTP Repositories, loading "http://localhost:8080/openrdf-workbench" will enable the default "SYSTEM" repository to be accessed.
```

Comment: What version of Tomcat and Sesame are you using ? If you don't replace the create.xsl file with the custom version provided for managing a Virtuoso repository, does the "new repository" link load providing a list of default repositories for Sesame ie "In Memory", "Java Native" etc ? Also, are any erros reported in the tomcat log file (~/logs/catalina.out) ?

Comment: I am using tomcat6 and Sesame version 2.6.5 . i downloaded the sesame 2.6.5 version and copy the create.xsl into openrdf workbench to restore sesame's old position but still i am getting this error upon click the create new repository. Error loading stylesheet: A network error occurred loading an XSLT stylesheet:http://lovalhost:8080/openrdf-workbench/transformations/create.xsl .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of version Virtuoso Sesame provider did you use?
NOTE:
Virtuoso Sesame provider ver >= 2.7.3 required virtjdbc4.jar file(Virtuoso JDBC driver) instead of virtjdbc3.jar.